# Como extrair dados específicos de um arquivo texto com Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tenho um *[*arquivo texto de 49633 linhas](https://ufile.io/62qph)** (arquivo.txt) com o seguinte formato:

```
 -e  Tue Mar 28 20:17:01 -03 2017 

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        239956     126484     113472       4904      10292      52280
-/+ buffers/cache:      63912     176044
Swap:       496636          0     496636 

 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 113460  10292  52308    0    0  1706    67  532  828 15 10 74  1  0

-e  Tue Mar 28 20:18:01 -03 2017 

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        239956     132808     107148       4904      10796      54872
-/+ buffers/cache:      67140     172816
Swap:       496636          0     496636 

 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 107656  10796  54872    0    0   654    29  219  353  6  4 90  0  0

-e  Tue Mar 28 20:19:01 -03 2017 

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        239956     132136     107820       4904      10824      54892
-/+ buffers/cache:      66420     173536
Swap:       496636          0     496636 

 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 107776  10824  54892    0    0   400    19  147  243  3  2 94  0  0
```

Gostaria de extrair o valor id do campo CPU, dado um intervalo de tempo. Por exemplo:

```
inicio=Mar 28 20:17:01

fim = Mar 28 20:19:01
```

imprimiria:

```
data                  id           
Mar 28 20:17:01,      74
Mar 28 20:18:01,      90
Mar 28 20:19:01,      94
```

Estou tentando mas não consegui escrever nenhuma linha de código além de:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


F = open(“arquivo.txt”,”r”)
```

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Nem ler a data de início e fim você conseguiu?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss: só consegui ler o arquivo!

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss: eu realmente não sei!

Comment: A saída mais simples que vejo é utilizar expressões regulares. Leia sobre a biblioteca `re`, nativa do Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ainda estou aprendendo Python, mas veja se é isso que você precisa:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
arq = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
texto = arq.readlines()
x = 0
Saida = ""
for linha in texto:
    Array = linha.split()
    if x != 1:
      print("data                  id")
      x+=1
    if (len(Array) == 7 and Array[0] == '-e'):
      Saida += Array[2] + ' ' + Array[3] + ' ' + Array[4]
    if (len(Array) > 7 and Array[14] in Array and Array[14] != 'id'):
      Saida += ',      ' + Array[14] + "\n"
print(Saida)
arq.close()
```

Caso queira fazer testes, aqui https://repl.it/Jy2Z

**Atualização:**
Fiz uma melhoria no código, em sua pergunta você disse que o arquivo tem cerca de 49633 linhas então suponho que tenhas varias datas também, então criei uma função para retornar o resultado entre intervalo de data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import *
# dia   mes   ano   horario
#  28    03   2017  20:17:01
#  %d    %m   %Y    %X
def retornaResultado(DataInicio, DataFinal):
  arq = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
  Inicio = int(datetime.strptime(DataInicio, '%d %m %Y %X').timestamp())
  Final  = int(datetime.strptime(DataFinal,  '%d %m %Y %X').timestamp())
  texto = arq.readlines()
  x = 0
  Saida = ""
  DataArquivo = ""
  for linha in texto:
      Array = linha.split()
      if x != 1:
        print("data                  id")
        x+=1
      if (len(Array) == 7 and Array[0] == '-e'):
        DataArquivo = int(datetime.strptime(Array[3] + ' ' + Array[2] + ' ' + Array[6] + ' ' + Array[4],  '%d %b %Y %X').timestamp())
        if DataArquivo >= Inicio and DataArquivo <= Final:
          Saida += Array[2] + ' ' + Array[3] + ' ' + Array[4]
      if (len(Array) > 7 and Array[14] in Array and Array[14] != 'id'):
        if DataArquivo >= Inicio and DataArquivo <= Final:
          Saida += ',      ' + Array[14] + "\n"
  print(Saida)
  arq.close()

# Exemplo de uso
retornaResultado('28 03 2017 20:17:01', '28 03 2017 20:17:01')
```

Como **utilizar:** execute a função: **retornaResultado**, passando duas datas no formato: **DIA MES ANO HORÁRIO**

Ao utilizar a **função** não é necessário fornecer o horário exato, você pode por exemplo colocar 00:00:00 sendo assim ele retorna os resultado iniciando com o horário 00:00:00 até 23:59:59.

Comment: vou testar! Obrigado

Comment: sao várias datas, cada qual com seus dados

Comment: Certo, então o uso da função é a melhor opção.

Comment: aqui está o arquivo: https://ufile.io/62qph

Comment: Desculpe-me agora não consigo ver o arquivo devido ás configurações da maquina em que estou, pois tem restrições de acesso a sites.

Comment: erros: http://imgur.com/a/Xixur

Comment: Rsrs  como eu disse, não tenho acesso a todas urls. Informe aqui em comentário o erro

Comment: aqui você consegue (google drive): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8_itjSdUyTtM3RNR2ttVU5UVWs

Comment: coloquei no google drive!

Comment: Também não consigo.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gopala/Desktop/Ler_free_vmstat_output.py", line 33, in <module>
    retornaResultado('28 03 2017 20:17:01', '28 03 2017 20:17:01')
  File "/home/gopala/Desktop/Ler_free_vmstat_output.py", line 10, in retornaResultado
    Inicio = int(datetime.strptime(DataInicio, '%d %m %Y %X').timestamp())
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Comment: Esqueceu de importar datetime. Coloque no inicio: from datetime import *  .... Veja como está o segundo código que coloquei.

Comment: from datetime import * já estava lá sim!

Comment: Para melhor ajudar você, coloque o código aqui https://repl.it e salva e manda a url

Comment: https://repl.it/teacher/classrooms/26312/drafts

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63382/discussion-between-wmsouza-and-ed-s).